# Not able to group Google Analytics custom events by page

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, analytics

I have custom events being successfully tracked in Google Analytics.

However, when adding a secondary dimension of `page`, or when creating a custom report to group custom events by page, my numbers go way off. The `total events` number goes down, and half of the events that I saw in the unfiltered report are no longer there. My custom report is setup quite standard from what I can tell. Does anybody have any experience or similar issues to this? Are we not tracking something correctly?

[image: Google Analytics Custom Report]

Comment: Just to exclude the obvious, check if there are events that are not attached to a pageview - this might happen if you have event code but no pageview calls, or when you accidentally create a new tracker between pageview- and event-tracking call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't realize it was possible to send custom events outside of a pageview. I'll start the search, but if you have any documentation to support how that works, I'm all ears!

Comment: For reference, my pages _are_ being tracked, so I assumed that the pageviews weren't technically related to events. Is there a way to pass the current page with the event? How does GA know the event happened on a specific page?